# attrs value undefined in directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing scope value to directive using `attrs`. I am getting undefined value of `min` when it load first time but works fine with $watch. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/653/)

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(function (){return attrs.min}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
    console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
     //do something
   });
   console.log(attrs.min);                       
 }
```

Comment: Do you really need $watch ? I mean, why not using an isolate scope binding ?

Comment: I'm probably missing something but what is the problem?

Comment: Oh, I got it, he wonders why `console.log(attrs.min);` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use **$observe** instead?

```
app.directive('exampleDirective1', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe('min', function(newValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
        });

    }
};
```

});

Comment: i need old value too

Comment: store the old value on a local variable. At directives (or components) the $observe is the recommended method to look properties

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the {{message}} is not evaluated before the directive is postlink.

You could also use a scope:

```
app.directive('exampleDirective1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            min: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
             scope.$watch('min', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
                console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
                //do something
            });
            console.log(scope.min);
            console.log(attrs.min);
        }
    };
});
```

And

```
With template: <example-directive1 min="message"></example-directive1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's strange, made an example with compile, prelink and postlink with lots of logs, and got strange results:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'hello';
    console.log('$scope.message set to hello');   
}

app.directive('exampleDirective1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
          console.log('currently at compile, attrs.min = ', tAttrs.min);

            return {
              post: function postLink(scope, elm, attrs) {
                 scope.$watch(function (){return attrs.min}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log('currently, attrs.min = ', attrs.min);  
                });
                console.log('currently at postlink, attrs.min = ', attrs.min);                       
              },
              pre: function prelink(scope,elm , attrs) {
                console.log('currently at prelink, attrs.min = ', attrs.min);  
              }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdzLhpf9/

The scope value is already set when prelink runs. But still, the arguments seem to be evaluated between postlink and prelink.

*EDIT:*
After some more digging, seems like $compile initializes args to 'undefined' in your angular version. See https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js at line 4434.